# un-renaming the REFERENCES page, with gatech-thesis and natbib

Tags: natbib, thesis

I'm using the `gatech-thesis` documentclass with the `natbib` package.

When I use `natbib`, the title of the references section title changes from `REFERENCES` to `Bibliography`.  I want to change it back to `REFERENCES`.

I've seen some posts that talk about using the `babel` package and `\renewcommand` appropriately for `report` or `article` document class, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my MWE, thanks in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
% would like to uncomment this package without renaming the references section
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\references
\end{document}
```

Worst cast scenario, I'd could abandon `natbib` in order to get the formatting right; but I'd rather not have to.

EDIT:  I compile it with:  `pdflatex foo.tex; bibtex foo.tex; pdflatex foo.tex` and the output is a single page with either REFERENCES or Bibliography at the top, depending on whether `natbib` is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (TL 2014), not much ado...

`\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}` does the job, since `natbib` only uses a `\providecommand{\bibname}`, so it's possible to redefine the macro either before or after `\usepackage{natbib}`

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 

\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\references
\end{document}
```

### Alternative solution, for usage with babel

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage[english,strings]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 

\StartBabelCommands{english}{extras}%
\SetString{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\EndBabelCommands

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\references
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `natbib` package uses `\bibsection` for the chapter title and it basically defines it as

```
\chapter*{\bibname}
```

if `\chapter` is defined. So it's sufficient to reinstate the `gatech-thesis` way:

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
% code in lines 2660-2664 of gatech-thesis.cls
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
 \chapter*{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}
    \@mkboth{\scshape\MakeUppercase\refname}%
            {\scshape\MakeUppercase\refname}%
    \pagestyle{\body@pagestyle}% REFERENCES uses BODY pagestyle, not endmatter.
    \vskip 0.5in
}
\makeatother

\bibfiles{xampl} % use your own

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello!}

A citation: \cite{article-minimal}

Another: \cite{mastersthesis-minimal}

\references

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is independent of `babel`, because it uses `\refname` and not a fixed string.