# Changing my \bibliography title

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to change the title of my `\bibliography`, which currently appears as "Bibliographic References". However, it is for a dissertation and it is necessary to leave everything in capital letters, that is, "BIBLIOGRAPHIC REFERENCES".

Here is the preamble of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   %[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[portuguese, brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\mdseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\mdseries\large}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{1em}{\thechapter~}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{8pt}


%configuração do pacote listings
\lstset{numbers=left,stepnumber=1,firstnumber=1,numberstyle=\tiny,extendedchars=true,breaklines=true,frame=tb,basicstyle=\footnotesize,stringstyle=\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,morecomment=[l]{//},morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},}
%fim da configuração

\setlength{\oddsidemargin }{17mm}  % margem esquerda para paginas impares
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{17mm}  % margem esquerda para paginas espelho
\setlength{\topmargin}{8mm}       % distancia da margem superior ao cabecalho 0
\setlength{\footskip}{20mm}       % distancia do texto ao rodape  15
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}     % tamanho do cabecalho
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}         % distancia do cabecalho ao inicio do texto
\setlength{\textheight}{205mm}    % comprimento do texto na pagina230
\setlength{\textwidth}{137mm}     % largura do texto na pagina 154
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}         % distancia entre dois paragrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{10mm}


\newcommand{\fix}[1]{{\color{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\remover}[1]{\st{#1}}
\newcommand{\incluir}[1]{{\color{green}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\trocar}[2]{\remover{#1} \incluir{#2}}



\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill\rule{2.5mm}{2.5mm}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{8-Abreviacoes}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figura\ }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tabela\ }

\newlength{\mylenf}
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2.4em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus-1ex\@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\large\bfseries\itshape}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus-1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\large\mdseries\itshape}}
\makeatother
```

And here is the rest of my document:

```
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\input{1-capa.tex}
\input{2-ContraCapa}
\input{3-Agradecimentos}
\input{4-Resumo}
\input{5-Abstract}

% LISTA DE FIGURAS
\listoffigures\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage

% LISTA DE TABELAS
\listoftables\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}
\printacronyms[name= \centering Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas\thispagestyle{empty}]
\clearpage   
\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
% CAPÍTULOS
\input{10-Introdução}
\input{11-ReferencialTeoricoEducacional}
\input{12-0-ReferencialTeoricoML}
\input{13-TrabRelac}
\input{14-DescricaoExperimentos}
\input{15-AnaliseResultados}
\input{16-Conclusão}    
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sbc-template}
\input{17-Apendice}
\input{18-Anexos}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult for me to verify that this solution will work for you, as I cannot compile your example document.

You appear to be using [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib), however. In that case, you can change your bibliography title using the below, adapted from a [similar prior answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457644/134641) (also see [another similar answer, with an explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210762/134641)).

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{BIBLIOGRAPHIC REFERENCES}}
```

Alternatively, the below command should automatically make whatever existing (`natbib`) Bibliography section name is set, to render in all-caps:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}
```

It would likely be better for you to switch to using the [more modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/134641) [BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8416/134641).